# How can I switch 2 textboxes data at the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 textboxes, textbox1 and textbox 2;

A user enters data into textbox1 and 2, I then need to be able to at the push of a button in C# reverse the 2 textboxes so that what was in textbox2 is now in 1. I naively thought this would be simple but of course when I tried this code once the first box has been changed the program doesn't know what was originally in the other textbox so both outcomes become what was in txt2:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt1.Text = ""+ txt2.Text + "";
        txt2.Text = "" + txt1.Text + "";
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need a temporary variable to store the value from one before you overwrite it with another. This is actually just a *how to swap too variables* question.

Answer (score 8):

Simply use an intermediary variable...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text1 = txt1.Text;
    txt1.Text = txt2.Text;
    txt2.Text = text1;
}
```

BTW the empty strings you placed at either end of your assignment statements are redundant.

Comment: *the empty strings you placed at either end of your assignment statements are redundant I think.* - they are completely redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one too:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
 String a, b;
        a = textBox1.Text;
        b = textBox2.Text;

        textBox1.Text = b;
        textBox2.Text = a;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is equivalent to the existing ones, it is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tehreem Ishtiaq Siddiqi said and @ADyson more specific confirms the actual code could be:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms_ExchangeTextsInTextBoxes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = "textFromTextBox1";
            textBox2.Text = "textFromTextBox2";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string textFromTextBox1 = textBox1.Text;
            string textFromTextBox2 = textBox2.Text;
            textBox1.Text = textFromTextBox2;
            textBox2.Text = textFromTextBox1;
        }
    }
}
```